# How to get the maximum integer value for $1+\sin^2\alpha$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The problem is as follows:

> Assume: $\alpha \in \left[ \frac{\pi}{2},\, 4 \right\rangle$
> (Read as alpha belonging to the interval closed in $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and open in $4$).
>
> $B=1+\sin^2\alpha$
>
> Find the maximum integer value that it can take $B$.

The choices given are:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\textrm{4}\\
2.&\textrm{3}\\
3.&\textrm{0}\\
4.&\textrm{2}\\
\end{array}$

I'm stuck here from the very beginning. **How exactly should I find the maximum integer value for that expression here**?.

Does it exist a criteria for this?. I'm requesting for help here because I feel lost.

I think I could use:

$-1 < \sin \alpha < 1$

But I doubt that's the approach right for here. Can someone help me here?. This topic isn't well covered in my precalculus book. But I'm certain that such simple approach would be used. As I mentioned, it is not much that I can offer. Some other ideas which had come to my mind are perhaps the use of.

$AM\geq GM$

But I don't know if such would be used or have to be used?.

Other approach could be derivatives.

Trying this would be:

$B(\alpha)=1+\sin^2\alpha$

$B'(\alpha)=2\sin\alpha\cdot \cos\alpha$

Equating this to zero yields:

$2\sin\alpha\cdot \cos\alpha = 0$

$\sin 2\alpha = 0$

Hence this can take values in the given range:

$2\alpha \in \left[ \pi,\, 8 \right\rangle$

Gee, $8$ is somewhat close to $2.54 \pi$

Then this means I have to look for values equal to zero in that range:

Those would be:

$\pi$, $2\pi$

But since it is divided by two for \alpha would be:

$\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi$.

This means:

Inserting any of these values in the function would give me the maximum?.

But again this would make any of those values $B=1$ and none of those values appears in the choices. Thus can someone help me here?.

Comment: What you said, that -1 < sin x < 1, isn't true.  It's close, but it isn't true.  If you figure out the real statement, it will make the question easy to answer.

Comment: What is the meaning of $\left[ \frac{\pi}{2},\, 4 \right\rangle$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I've updated my question to clear your doubt but mine it still unresolved, can you further help me?

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell: Why not just write $[\frac{\pi}{2},4)$?

Comment: I did answer, what more do you need ? The question is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Since $-1\leq \sin(x)\leq 1$ for *any* $x$, then $0\leq \sin^2(x)\leq 1$ and $1\leq 1+\sin^2(x)\leq 2$ for *any* $x$. That immediately gets rid of all but one option.

I guess the only remaining thing is to make sure the question is not posed under a false premise and that you actually *do* achieve the value $2$ at *some* point between $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $4$. That would require you to find some $x$ in that interval where $\sin^2(x)=1$, or equivalently where $\sin(x)=1$ or $\sin(x)=-1$. We know exactly at which points $\sin(x)$ takes those values, so then all you need to do is check whether any of them are in the interval you are interested in.

Comment: So I guess that the answer would be $2$ or choice number 4?. Was there any part in my approach that was any close to getting the right answer?. As you can see I've attempted to use derivatives but this didn't worked out as I expected.

Comment: Well from reading your answer again. I'm getting that $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ so that $\sin x=1$ I mean on the first quadrant, and will do so forth for their multiples, isn't it. While for the lower boundary I mean $\sin x =-1$ it will require that $\frac{2n+1}{2}\pi$. I'm not entirely sure of this, thus I am asking for your confirmation.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell: Calculus would give you the relative extremes of the function, but you don't know if that maximum is an integer. Note also that because your interval is not finite and closed, you have no guarantee that the function has a maximum or minimum value (it does, but you don't know that ahead of time for sure), so that Calculus may not even be relevant. You could try to find those relative extremes and see if they provide you information, but because they will be relative, you still need to do a lot of extra work to make sure what you find answers the question. (cont)

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell: Honestly, this is not a question about calculus. This is a question about knowing basic information about the sine function. Yes, your function does in fact take the value $2$, and it takes it at $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and at $x=\frac{3\pi}{2}$; those are the only two values in the interval in question where $\sin(x)$ takes the value $1$ or $-1$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: $\sin^2 \frac{\pi}{2} = 1$. And of course $\sin^2 x \le 1$ for all other $x$.

Comment: Okay but how does that help me into getting the answer?. I'm still stuck with your solution. Can you offer more details please?.

Answer (score 0):

The only integer values achieved by $\sin^2\alpha$ are $0$ and $1$ (for $\alpha=k\frac\pi2$). Depending on the allowed range of $\alpha$, you can tell which holds.